# Python Index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I'm trying to calculate the binomial coefficient between two elements of the following arrays:

```
popul_num = np.array([100, 200, 0, 0]) --> #The discrete number of entities in each reaction
LHS = np.array([[1,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0]]) --> #three rows for 3 different reactions, each row has 4 elements describing the ratio of reactants in that particular reaction
stoch_rate = np.array([0.0016, 0.0001, 0.1000])
```

My system has 4 entities; Enzyme, substrate, enzyme-substrate complex and product. Which are described by discrete reactant numbers in the popul_num and as ratios between the reactants in LHS matrices, in that order.

The binomial coefficient should be calculated using each entities discrete number of molecules and its ratio between the other entities in the that particular reaction given in LHS. Which will lead to a propensity function for that reaction (see below)

I asked a question the other day when i got the the indexing error: `index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3` but that was fixed by making sure i was referencing the indices instead of the values.

But in that version of my code I was using matrices instead of arrays, I've since realised that the length of the popul_num matrix was 1 so i was always 0 and my binomial coefficient calculation didn't work. So  I converted my matrices into arrays with an aim to flattening the popul_num array into a 1D array with length 4 --> (not sure if this is the best method though any other suggestions welcome)

But I'm getting the `index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3` error again and I don't know why? Is there a difference in the way python for loops reference values or indices in matrices and arrays?

This is the code I've got so far:

```
for j in range(len(LHS)):
    cj = stoch_rate
    for i in range(len(popul_num)):
        if i >= LHS[i,j]:        
            binon_rxn = binom(i, LHS[i, j])     # binomial coefficent isnt working! Always returns 1! 
            print(binon_rxn)        
            aj = cj*binon_rxn            
        else: 
            cj == 0           
            aj = (cj*binom(i, LHS[i, j]))
    print("Propensity function per reaction:\n", aj)
```

Comment: What is the value `stoch_rate` in your case? Also, how do you calculate `binom`?

Comment: Oh sorry I've edited the post but here they are as well stoch_rate = np.array([0.0016, 0.0001, 0.1000]), I'm calculating the binomial coefficient using the inbuilt binom, which i think comes from scipy but I've also got numpy imported (I'm on python 3.7 btw)

Comment: `for i in range(len(popul_num)):`  where `popul_num` is length 4. `binon_rxn = binom(i, LHS[i, j])` will through that error when `i==3` since LHS is only of length 3.

Comment: How do I write that with the correct syntax sorry ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the iterators of the two for loops. The first iterator should be `i` not `j` and also the second should be `j` instead of `i`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import binom


popul_num = np.array([100, 200, 0, 0])
LHS = np.array([[1,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0]])
stoch_rate = np.array([0.0016, 0.0001, 0.1000])

for i in range(len(LHS)):  #change this to `i`
    cj = stoch_rate
    for j in range(len(popul_num)): # change this to `j`
        if i >= LHS[i,j]:        
            binon_rxn = binom(i, LHS[i, j])     # binomial coefficent isnt working! Always returns 1! 
            print(binon_rxn)        
            aj = cj*binon_rxn            
        else: 
            cj == 0           
            aj = (cj*binom(i, LHS[i, j]))
    print("Propensity function per reaction:\n", aj)
```

which gots this output:

```
1.0
1.0
Propensity function per reaction:
 [0.0016 0.0001 0.1   ]
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
Propensity function per reaction:
 [0.0016 0.0001 0.1   ]
1.0
1.0
2.0
1.0
Propensity function per reaction:
 [0.0016 0.0001 0.1   ]
```

Comment: Okay in that case should I swap round the [i, j] to [j, i]in the binomial coefficient calculation as well? Because I still don't think that bits working properly, the output of the binomial should change if i change the discrete numbers of molecules in popul_num which it doesn't atm

Comment: I don't know the idea behind your code in order to tell you why `binon_rxn` doesn't return the expected value. Do you use a certain tutorial?

Comment: Heres a link to what I'm trying to implement:  https://github.com/karinsasaki/gillespie-algorithm-python/blob/master/build_your_own_gillespie_exercises.ipynb, but this is in python 2.7 so I've had to adapt parts of it and ignore other parts etc, I think the most useful bit is at the bottom when they automate it using matrices/arrays

Comment: I'm so sorry, It's hard for me to follow all of this!

Comment: No worries! Thanks for trying anyway :)